# login in vb.net and sql server 2008

Tags: vb.net

How I'm going to redirect to another page after login is successful ?
and how I'm going to check if the username & password are correct or not ?

this is my code for login :

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click

   If txtUser.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter The Username !", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)

    ElseIf txtPass.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter The Password !", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)


    End If

    Dim connectionString As String = "server=''; user id=''; password=''; Database=''"
    Dim conLogin As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString)

    Dim queryString As String = "SELECT login VALUES " _
    & "(@username, @password) "
```

Comment: Why don't you use Linq to Sql or Entity framework to perform this task?. Or just an stored procedure. Using hardcoded sql is not a good idea for maintenance

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn SQL first: The following statement is not correct SQL.

```
SELECT login VALUES (@username, @password)
```

The statement should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Login WHERE UserName = @username AND Password = @password
```

Then you need to set the command parameters `@username` and `@password`.

I also doubt that the connection string you're using is correct. Use an `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` to create a correct connection string. In addition, you do not open the connection, so there's not database access possible.

Comment: how i'm going to open the database connection ?

Comment: `conLogin.Open` - but maybe you should start by reading one of the basic tutorials about SQL access in VB.NET which you can find but using Google.

Comment: something like this: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/32392-sql-basics-in-vbnet/

Answer (score 1):

To redirect to another page, see code below

```
response.redirect("abc.apsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use datareader and this sql query

```
Select count(*) from Login where UserName = @username and Password = @password

if (dr > 0) {
response.redirect('home');
}
else{
//error message
}
```

just search about datareader.......
...Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code for Login Function.

For more details visit my blog : http://uncopyrightables2011.blogspot.com/
or Tweet me : [@MaxRohana](https://twitter.com/MaxRohana)

```
Private Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
    ConnectToSQL()

End Sub

Private Sub ConnectToSQL()

    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim Passowrd As String
    Dim Passowrd2 As String
    Dim userName As String

    Try
        If
            'change the data source and initial catalog according to your sql server engine and data base
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source = YOUR-PC; Initial Catalog = YOUR-DB; Integrated Security = True"
            con.Open()

            cmd.Connection = con
            'change the data fields names and table according to your database
            cmd.CommandText = " SELECT  UserName, Password FROM   AdminDetail WHERE   (UserName = '" & txtUsername.Text & "' ) AND (Password = '" & txtPassword.Text & "')"

            Dim lrd As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If lrd.HasRows Then
                While lrd.Read()

                    'Do something here
                    Passowrd = lrd("Password").ToString()
                    userName = lrd("UserName").ToString()

                    Passowrd2 = txtPassword.Text()

                    If Passowrd = Passowrd2 And userName = txtUsername.Text Then

                        MessageBox.Show("Logged in successfully as " & userName, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information
                                        )
                        frmMain.Show()
                        Me.Hide()

                        'Clear all fields
                        txtPassword.Text = ""
                        txtUsername.Text = ""

                    End If

                End While

            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Username and Password do not match..", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                'Clear all fields
                txtPassword.Text = ""
                txtUsername.Text = ""
            End If

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while connecting to SQL Server." & ex.Message)

    Finally
        con.Close() 'Whether there is error or not. Close the connection.

    End Try

End Sub
```